# actions on google Testing instruction not found when trying to release alpha

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to test my Dialogflow app on Actions on Google.
I managed to release one alpha version without a problem but now when I try to release the second version it gives an error
Testing instruction not found.
And then nothing happens. I couldn't find this error anywhere, neither does it take to some dialog to fix it.
What does this mean and how was I able to create one alpha version for the same project without error?

Comment: Are you trying to incorporate sign-in or account linking to your action?

Comment: Yes, I am. But this works in the simulator properly but I can't release it in alpha.

Comment: Looks like you were right. I disabled the account linking option and it is now deploying my alpha. Strange!
Thanks

Comment: When you add account linking, you need to including instructions for the reviewers to test. If not, there will be a problem.

Comment: Thanks Nick, you can put this as an answer so I can approve it for you. 
The documentation is not very clear. I still have to figure out how to write the testing instructions.
btw, Google came back with the same answer as you but based on your suggestion I had already tried it and it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: This looks like a bug, because when you chose Google Sign In, there is no testing instructions field to fill

Comment: @DanielCukier have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we determined in the comments, you added account linking in your second version. When you add some sort of account linking, you need to give directions to the review team so they can fully test the capabilities of your actions. This should be stated in the *Testing Instructions* section at the bottom of the account linking section.

Comment: Thanks for helping with this. 
Actually I had account linking in the first version also but it still worked. When I tried a second alpha release it didn't work. I removed the account linking so that the alpha version works.
I have told this to Google and they are looking if there is a bug somewhere in the Actions on Google product because if I hadn't completed everything it shouldn't have allowed me to create an alpha for the first version also.
I have also told them to take the user the problem when the click on the error that shows up.

Comment: Just to clarify further go to the directory information section on the left of the Actions on Google Console.
Create a gmail account for testing and provide the login and password for this account in the Testing Instructions sections.
You also have to provide a URL to the Terms of Service.

Comment: i select Google Sign in method in account linking. But it is not showing Testing instructions. And i am going to release to version. it is throwing an error for "testing instruction not found"

Comment: I confirm what @SudhanshuJain says. Choosing **Account creation** -> **Yes, allow users to sign up for new accounts via voice**, and **Linking type** -> **Google Sign In**, there is no **Testing Instruction** section. But, it still doesn't allow us to do the deploy.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are not finding the **Testing Instruction** section in **Advanced Options** > **Account Linking** menu, you can find it under:

**Deploy** > **Directory Information** > **Additional Information** > **Testing Instructions**

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53204531/3944251)