# Actions on Google, Beta Release: Testing instruction not found

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Basically, I have the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51692257/3944251) question here. The accepted answer in that question suggests that we should *give directions to the review team* in *Testing Instructions* section.

But in my case, which is:

1. Account creation: **Yes, allow users to sign up for new accounts via voice**
2. Linking type: **Google Sign In**
3. Client information: **my_client_id**

There is **NO Testing Instructions** section. But, when I try to do the deploy, it will still demand me to give the instructions and won't allow me to do the deploy.

How am I supposed to deal with this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer state the test instructions should be added in the Testing Instructions section at the bottom of the **account linking section** did you check here?

These can be found in actions on google console by going to Advanced Options > Acountlinking > Testing instructions

Hope that this helps.

**EDIT**: My bad, those are the instructions for 0auth. Another option for providing Test instructions is via Deploy > Directory Information > Testing Instructions in the actions on google console. This option is available for me when i choose Google Sign-in in accountlinking.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSHy2.png)

Comment: **Post Edit** Thank you. I found it now. But probably Google should give us a better documentation over this.